# What datastructure to use for dot access to key and value

Tags: javascript, data-structures

What datastructure i Javascript will work like this? :

ROLES.ADMIN return "admin"
ROLES.ADMIN.TESTERS returns "admin.testers"

I tried with an object but the was no good.

```
ROLES = {
  ADMIN:{
    TESTERS:"testers",
    BOSS:"boss"
  }
}
```

As you can see..i need some sort of datastructure that also gives me a value for the key ADMIN, as well as the ADMINS sub values.

Comment: You cannot have `ROLES.ADMIN` be a string and at the same time have a `.TESTERS` property. There is no such data structure. What do you need this for?

Comment: So, we use this type of structure to manage access in our react application.
So "departmentA" gives you access to dep a and "departmentA.worksheet" gives you access to more. To stop using text here we wanted some sort of datastructure to help with this. So we could do this: ROLES.DEPARTMENTA   ROLES.DEPARTMENTA.WORKSHEET

Comment: You're still using text if accessing that data structure returns text, no? Why do you want to "*stop using text*"? What happens to that text, are you doing string comparisons only? Sending it in network requests? Storing it in databases? What else?

Comment: Its just for controlling the frontend. So...i want the datastructur to stop us from mistyping.. "departmentA" and "departmentA.worksheet" works fine as string..but when you use it 10 places..and want to change it..no good.

Comment: Solution a: Use TypeScript with a union string type. Solution b: Use `ROLES.ADMIN_TESTERS` instead of `ROLES.ADMIN.TESTERS`. Write a unit test that the `ROLES.ADMIN` value is a prefix of `ROLES.ADMIN_…` if you require that. Solution c: drop strings entirely and just use `ROLES = { ADMIN: { TESTERS: {}, BOSS: {}, }, }`, comparing those objects by identity.

Comment: You could also create a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to alter the values you return. Though i'm not sure how this would work for nested objects

Comment: @Reyno i tried Proxy but i cant return ADMIN string for ROLES.ADMIN and at the same time return string "ADMIN.BOSS" for ROLES.ADMIN.BOSS